# Загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: php, linux

Написал скрипт по загрузке файла на сервер со стороны клиента.

Файл загружается, но не перемещается из директории с временными файлами в нужную мне директорию. Пишет failed to open stream: Permission denied in (адрес скрипта который обрабатывает перемещение) on line 20.
и ниже вторая ошибка Unable to move /tmp/phpblablabla to (директория для перемещения файла)

скажу сразу, что я покурил мануалы на php.net по поводу функции move_uploaded_file и написал так как там рекомендуют учитывая все пожелания.

*Файл не копируется!*

Comment: также работал с chmod для скрипта и загружаемого файла. и использовал похожую утилиту только для папок. ничего не помогает.

возможно проблема где-то в файле php.ini но я не знаю что там исправлять.

Comment: Возможно проблема в файле php.ini где указано на максимальный размер файла? Хотя возможно не суть!

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется все дело в пользователе php, посмотри какой пользователь и группа у файлов во временной директории и попробуй дать ему права на доступ в нужную папку. Используй chown для смены пользователя и группы. Синтаксис команды, по-моему, такой:

```
 chown user:group /var/www/* -R.
```

А, вообще, **man** chown

Как вариант, если ось Red Hat или Centos - то отключи selinux.

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: php это такой пользователь? у меня /tmp и /var/www/ рутовые. сервер стартует под рутом.
у меня Linux Ubuntu

Comment: с правами не выходит. но заметил одну ерунду.
когда сайт загружает файл, он его помещает в /tmp вместо /var/www/temp которую я указал в upload_tmp_dir